# How would I append multiple cells with one input?

Tags: excel

Forgive me if the title is misleading, I am not a programming whiz and I have tried my best to describe my problem, which is:

I have 2 sheets, one that the user interacts with called "calc" and one for data storage called "data". The basic setup of calc is as follows.

```
Item    Quantity    Sub-Total
blah        2         $ xx.xx
blah        1         $ xx.xx

Ingredient    Amount required
Ingred. 1            x
Ingred. 2            x
```

The basic setup of data has 2 tables, one for a recipe and one for prices of ingredients.

```
Item    Ingred. 1    Ingred. 2    Ingred 3. ... ... ...
 A          0            1            1
 B          1            0            0
 C          1            1            0

Ingredient    Price
Ingred. 1     $xx.xx
Ingred. 2     $xx.xx
Ingred. 3     $xx.xx
```

I've been trying for 3 days now to come up with a solution to my problem and I fear that I am slowly going insane. What I am trying to achieve is that when a user enters a quantity of a specific item in the "calc" sheet, it will pull data from the two tables in "data" and populate cells within "calc". If the user enters data hopefully it should end up as such:

calc Sheet

```
Item    Quantity    Sub-Total
 A         2         $ 60.00
 C         1         $ 70.00

Ingredient    Amount required
Ingred. 1            1
Ingred. 2            4
Ingred. 3            2
```

data Sheet

```
Item    Ingred. 1    Ingred. 2    Ingred 3. ... ... ...
 A          0            1            2
 B          2            0            0
 C          1            3            0

Ingredient    Price
Ingred. 1     $10.00
Ingred. 2     $20.00
Ingred. 3     $15.00
```

Could anybody show me how one would achieve the effect I am after? Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: Can you please elaborate how $ 60.00 is calculated in your calc sheet? Item A needs 1 x Ingr. 2 = $ 20.00 and 2 x Ingr. 3 = 2 x $ 15.00 = $ 30.00. That's in sum $ 50.00. This in quantity 2 = $ 100.00?  And same with "Amount required". For Item A we need 1 x Ingr. 2. But we have Item A in quantity 2 = 2 x Ingr. 2. For Item C we need 3 x Ingr. 2. That's in sum 5 x Ingr. 2. You show 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having the `data` sheet like so:

[image]

Then you can simply use `SUMPRODUCT`to calculate the prices per item:

Formula in `B4` downwards:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$ZZ$2,$C4:$ZZ4)
```

Then in the `calc` sheet:

[image]

Formula in `C2` downwards:

```
=$B2*VLOOKUP($A2,data!$A:$B,2)
```

With the "Amount required" it is much more complex since we must count the occurrences of the ingredient in all ingredients of the used items.

Formula in `F2` downwards:

```
{=SUM(IF(data!$A$4:$A$100=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$11),TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$11)*INDEX(data!$C$4:$ZZ$100,0,MATCH($E2,data!$C$3:$ZZ$3,0))))}
```

This is an array formula. Input it in the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets should then appear automatically.